# Unclaimed interfaces on Samsung n210

Tags: networking, wireless, system-installation, touchpad, samsung

I wanted to bring my netbook Samsung n210 back to life and decided to try it with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I first ran the Live version from my USB pen drive, and it worked like a charm! Everything was recognized, and I could also get Chrome + Netflix working on it.

The problem came when I then decided to install Ubuntu directly onto the netbook. Again, I booted from my USB and installed it, and everything finished correctly, but when I restarted and the newly installed Ubuntu loaded, the touchpad, USB, ethernet and wireless were not working.

This is my first time installing Linux, and also using it, so I'm kind on lost on what I can do to make it work.

When I do an `ifconfig` from the terminal I only see the Loopback.
Is there a way to make it work as it did with the live version?

Comment: Please don't post multiple unrelated questions at the same time. Can you [edit] it and remove the part about Chrome and Netflix? Search for similar issues or ask a new question, if you want. It would also be better to have treat the touch pad, Ethernet and USB separately.

Comment: David, I don't believe this are unrelated questions. I think that explaining why I'm doing this (because I want to use Netflix on my netbook) will be useful to avoid someone that was thinking on providing a solution that won't work with Netflix.
And about the interfaces, as all didn't worked, if I write one question for each issue, some can tell me, for example, to use the ethernet connection to fix the wireless one, and I will have to explain at that point that both things are not working. So here I'm putting all the information so that everyone can get as much information as I can.

Comment: I disagree with your counter-arguments. Issues with user applications and drivers for different pieces of hardware are rarely related. If you have reasons to suspect a relation, add the necessary info. If you want to avoid solutions that rely on network access by the affected machine, give a hint in your question to potential answerers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by installing Xubuntu 14.04.
Thank all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well you did right the first time - because it worked.
Try the live boot again.
Connect to the internet.
Now run the install from the install icon on your workspace, thatway it is installing with known drivers, some it will probably update - but with working configurations.

Somehow the live ISO's find more workable ways to handle hardware than the bare install does. This way worked for me more than a few times - specially with wireless. And on different distros, I gues that the gurus setting up the live iso's try to make it a plesent discovery, hence the ekstra effort spent on hardware configuration.

Have luck with your netbook.

Comment: Ok, I tried this but still didn't worked :( For some reason I got the same result as installing it from scratch.